# Upgrade PHP version to 8x from 7x in Xampp

Tags: php, xampp, php-8

I did these steps,

1. My old version is **7.3.11**
2. Downloaded PHP from https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.0-ts-vs16-x64
3. Deleted old php folder and added the new library
4. Modified `...\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf` file according to this:

Old:

```
LoadFile ".../xampp/php/php7ts.dll
LoadModule php7_module ".../xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

Now:

```
LoadFile ".../xampp/php/php8ts.dll
LoadModule php7_module ".../xampp/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

I think the `php7_module` after `LoadModule` is a variable. So, if I change it to `php8_module`, I may have to change everywhere.

Now, after starting apache, I'm getting this error:
[image]

Comment: You will have to check the logs, exactly as the message says. And you'll probably discover that the module name is not free-form.

Comment: @mario, Thanks. Which error I should check? https://ibb.co/k19FZcC

Answer (score 2):

Just change **LoadModule php7_module** to **LoadModule php_module** and it will work!